# Transparent NSWindow but with standard border and shadow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, transparent, nswindow

I want to have a more or less standard NSWindow with a toolbar and all that, but I want the content view to be transparent so that I can see through it. At the same time I want to keep the light gray outline of the window and also it's shadow. BUT I want to avoid the "inner" shadow I get from the toolbar inside the content view area.

What I have tried so far is just to set the window background color to a semi transparent color and also set opaque to NO. The problem is that the window border fades away with the alpha of the background itself, and the more transparency I have on the background, the more the shadow of the toolbar shows up within the content view.

Generally, the window shadow and border changes depending on the transparency of the content view, which I totally understand. But I want a behavior where it keeps the border and shadow just as if it was a completely opaque window, and then I want the content view area to be transparent.

I am not sure what I need to do conceptually to make it work. Maybe I have to draw the window border myself, maybe not. Maybe I need to draw the shadow myself, or maybe not.

Is there anyone that know how to build this? I don't need exact code details, but rather what parts I need to do custom..

I appreciate any input!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I dont't know if this is of any value for you after all this time but try:

```
[aWindow setOpaque:NO];
[aWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the NSView class, override the drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect method and set the color of the view as clearcolor, now set the class of your content view as the Subclass of NSView.